# Beamer: handouts and itemize not working as expected

Tags: beamer, itemize

I am trying to create handouts with beamer (it is the first time I am using it). As you can see from the minimal code below, I am passing `handouts` as an option. I would expect that overlays be neglected in the handouts. If you compile the code, however, you will find out that items in the itemize environment are displayed on separate pages.

Do you have any ideas why?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table,handouts]{beamer}

\date{Spring 2013}

\subtitle[Lecture 1]{Lecture 1 - The Need for Numerical Methods and Analysis}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{Contacting me}
    \begin{block}{My contact information:}
      Dr. XXX \\
      \texttt{xxx.yyy@zzz.ac.uk}
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{Office hours}
    Monday 2pm -- 4pm.
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Course content}
   \begin{block}{Overview}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
     \item Basic numerical analysis and some simple methods (6 lectures)
     \item Curve-fitting (2 lectures)
     \item Numerical differentiation and integration (quadrature) (5 lectures)
    \end{itemize}
   \end{block}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `handout` instead of `handouts`.